# Is it possible to see how many days a work item stays in each Board column?

Tags: azure-devops

We would like to track our work items and would like to see how many days an item stayed in each Board column before being moved to the next project phase (column). Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

There’s a way to see when the work items are moved that you can

- Click work item
- Click history [image]
- Check the History box inside. You can calculate by every changes date for the staying time. The date, path, column and operator information also display in it.